# Indention Error in django python code

Tags: python, django

I am getting an Indention Error. This code is straight from the django first tutorial.

```
class ChoiceInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Choice
    extra = 3 
class PollAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = [
        (None,               {'fields': ['question']}),
        ('Date information', {'fields': ['pub_date'], 'classes': ['collapse']}),
    ]
    inlines = [ChoiceInline] 
admin.site.register(Poll, PollAdmin)
```

Comment: I guess it also tells you the line number that throw this error.

Comment: check if you have any tab and whitespace mix, that's usually the problem.

Comment: Shit, I am really sorry. Actually i was editing the file in notepad++ and in that it was showing alright, but when i opened the file in IDLE, the `inlines = [ChoiceInline]` code was intended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works fine for me on python2.7, make sure you didn't mix tabs and spaces in your actual code. There is also an extra comma at the end of the second line in fieldsets, but that should be fine in python.

Comment: The comma is fine and actually encouraged in Python, so that new lines can be added to the list without having to modify existing lines.